# PHPUnit Post request for a Symfony2 controller

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am writing a little test that "should" change a database value based on the post request I send, but I check my test database and clearly nothing is changing. I know this API works because I did a test using CURL through the CLI and it was not a problem.

```
 $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/api/hardware_version/00-11-22-33-44-55', array('hardware_version' => 10));
```

The post param variable name is correct, but nothing is changing. What's the best way to send a post request in a PHPUnit functional test?

Comment: Your testing environment db is the same db you are checking?

Comment: Write your assertion in the test case and check with it if this works. I suggest to check if the response is succesfully, etc...

Comment: also you can check the test.log for any errors

Comment: Sorry guys, been at work. The test database was the correct database. I did what Matteo suggested. I basically played around with the JSON response returns and somehow found a resolution. It's a bit vague, so I'm not going to write an answer, since my knowledge on the resolve isn't very great..